# What is the structure of the Coxeter groups of type $\text{D}_n$

Tags: group-theory, root-systems, coxeter-groups

I am curious on the structure of the Coxeter group $G$ of type $\text{D}_n$. Here I let $\{e_1,\cdots,e_n\}$ be the standard basis of the vector space $\mathbb{R}^n$. Then I choose $$r_k=e_{k+1}-e_k~\mbox{for}~1\leqslant k<n~~~\mbox{and}~~~r_n=e_1+e_2$$to be the simple roots of $G$. So we will have the root system $\{e_i\pm e_j \mid i,j=1,\cdots,n~~\mbox{and}~~i\neq j\}$. Denote the reflection of $r_k$ by $\sigma_k$, and the reflection of $e_i+e_j$ by $f_{i,j}$. It is clear that $H:=\langle\sigma_1,\cdots,\sigma_{n-1}\rangle\cong\text{S}_n$ the symmetric group as it represents all the permutations of the standard basis $\{e_1,\cdots,e_n\}$. Then $\sigma_kf_{i,j}\sigma_k^{-1}=f_{i',j'}$ where $i',j'$ are the resulting elements of $i,j$ under the induced permutation of $\sigma_k$. Hence, we can think of $H$ acting on the set $\{f_{i,j} \mid \mbox{all possible}~i,j\}$. But then what is the next to deduce the explicit structure of $G$?

Comment: According to Humphreys (I didn't check the details), the addition of the extra root means you also get all sign-changes involving an even number of minuses (so you get a semidirect product $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^{n-1} \rtimes S_n$)

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft, yeah, I guess it is something like what you say. I believe $H=S_n$. But what are elements in the base group?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by the base group.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft, by the base group I meant $\mathbb{Z}_2^{n-1}$.

Comment: As I said, I didn't check the details. But they should be element that send an even number of the standard basis elements to their negative, and fixes the rest (how to express those in terms of the simple reflections should be doable with a bit of fiddling).

Comment: It seems to me that $\tau=\sigma_1\circ\sigma_n$ maps both $e_1$ and $e_2$ to their negatives, and keeps $e_3,e_4,\ldots,e_n$ fixed. You get other even sign changes by conjugating $\tau$ with permutations of your choice.

Comment: Take all conjugates of $\tau$ (they all change exactly two signs) and their products! What kind of a description are you looking for?

Comment: Or define a homomorphism from $G$ to $S_n$ by mapping both $\sigma_1,\sigma_n$ to the 2-cycle $(12)$, and by mapping $\sigma_k$ to the 2-cycle $(k;k+1)$. The group of sign changes is the kernel of that homomorphism.

Comment: You can split that homomorphism $f$ by mapping $S_n$ to the subgroup generated by $\sigma_1,\ldots,\sigma_{n-1}$ in the obvious way. That gives you the semidirect product
$$G\cong \ker f\rtimes S_n,$$ where $\ker f$ is exactly the sign changes, hence an elementary abelian two group. The element $\tau$ has enough conjugates to show that $|\ker f|=2^{n-1}$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, sorry, I still don't quite get it. For example, where $\sigma_2\circ\sigma_n$ is mapped to? And why $|ker f|=2^{n-1}$ but not $2^{n\choose 2}$?

Comment: There are only $n$ signs to change, and there must be an even number of changes? $$f(\sigma_2\circ\sigma_n)=f(\sigma_2)\circ f(\sigma_n)?$$

Comment: Dear @JyrkiLahtonen, I'm interested in your homomorphism $f$. By your definition, $\ker(f)=\{\sigma \in G \mid f(\sigma)=id\}$. I don't understand why $\ker(f)$ is the sign changes? Did you mean that $\ker(f)=\{\sigma^{-1}\tau\sigma \mid \sigma \in G\}$?